# optimizing RandomForestRegressor for other metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Documentation page for sklearn random forest says

> The only supported criterion is “mse” for the mean squared error.

My data is messy and has outliers and I feel that MAE or some robust penalty function would perform much better.

Is there are a way to fit random forest regressor for other metric, for example iteratively, or is there other python open source alternative, or is my assumption on requiring other metrics wrong on itself? Sklearn is very well developed in other areas, so this seems strange to me that only mse supported for such important approach as random forest.

Comment: What do you mean by "iteratively" here? You can add a different split criterion if you like, but you'll need some cython knowledge.

Comment: @AndreasMueller yep, I think 'iteratively' is a not applicable here, I thought about some complicated scheme with re-weighting. Thanks, I'll take a look at cython and scikit source code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) or [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV.html) to optimize for another criterion in a cross-validation loop. The forests themselves will still optimize for MSE, but the CV loop find the forest among the chosen parameter settings that optimizes the actual criterion that you're interested in. (And it optimizes for CV score, not training set score.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry, don't have enough reputation to vote up.
I am not sure about GridSearchCV here, while generally being good tuning tool, it will allow to select only minor things like tree depth or number of estimators, it will not influence split decision process itself.